# jQuery - hovering an element to add a class to it?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

```
$(".test").hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass("move");        
})
```

The above **jQuery** needs some fixing. My **CSS** selector is currently like this:

```
.test .selectme
```

and hovering over the `.test` element currently results in:

```
.test.move .selectme
```

I'm trying to get this instead when hovering over the `.test` element:

```
.test .selectme.move
```

So basically I need jQuery to give `.selectme` the `.move` class when I hover over the `parent` `.test`.

Comment: You are aware of the `:hover` pseudo-class in CSS right? You could just do `.test:hover .selectme` instead of adding the class with jQuery...

Comment: Yep I'm aware. But in my case I need the jQuery.

Comment: May I ask what you need the class for, specifically?

Comment: For an animation, which needs to be triggered upon hover, but needs to continue animating when unhovered. I cut the jQuery code short above to make it less confusing. But basically removing and adding the class to trigger the animation. The :hover unfortunately won't continue the animation if I unhover the element. That's why I needed the jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to find the `selectme` item inside `menu` then add the class to it

```
$(".menu").hover(function(){
  $(this).find('.selectme').addClass("move"); //You may use toggleClass('move') if you want to remove the class when the mouse leaves menu item
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".test").hover(function(){
    $('.selectme',this).addClass("move"); //This is simpler, find the selectme that's inside of .test
})
```